# Can Swift.h file be imported in pch file?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use swift in an Objective-C based project. It seems that ProjectName-Swift.h needs to be imported in every .m file which doesn't sound good. Can it be imported in the ProjectName-Prefix.pch like UIKit/UIKit.h so that I only need to type once in the project?

I've tried this way, but .pch cannot find the header file. Is there an alternative attempt?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately .pch cannot find the file